# Why can I add a bounty to already answered questions?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Some clarification: I didn't actually try to add a bounty to a question, I just noticed that in already answered questions (questions not created by me), the link for "add a bounty" is still available.

Does this makes sense?

For me, I would think it is great to be able to add bounties to already answered questions if I think the current answer is not satisfactory. However, it probably doesn't make any sense with the current stackexchange framework, since I wouldn't be able to vote for a new answer since the question doesn't belong to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bounties are assigned separately from accepted answers. You can add bounties to your questions or other people's.

See

- https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty
- [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: great, i wasn't aware it was now decoupled

Comment: I remember seeing a question with 1 accepted answer, 1 highest-voted answer, and 1 (or was it 2 partial bountyies?) bounty-given answer. ! (and also 1  answer which was actually good and relevant.)

Answer (score 3):

See

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

For additional context on the changes. There is *no* relationship between accepted answer and bounty now, at all.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the feature that Stack Exchange seems to let you do whatever.  Not only can you answer your own question, but you can answer it several times.  You can set bounties on things you've already selected an answer for, etc.  I believe you can even hold a bounty more than once for the same question.  I think it's nice that it doesn't *tell* you what to do and doesn't assume that one approach fits all things.

I'm not entirely sure if this is the kind of contribution is intended for meta btw, let me know if it's not.